# Homomorphic sorting of a vector of FHE ciphertexts

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Bonjour à tous,
Je dispose d'un vecteur contenant 15 nombre réel chiffrés avec les schéma de chiffrement homomorphe CKKS. Mon problème est que je souhaite trier ce vecteur par ordre croissant. Je ne sais pas comment m'y prendre. Votre aide me sera la bienvenue. Merci

*Hello everyone, I have a vector containing 15 real numbers encrypted with the CKKS homomorphic encryption scheme. My problem is that I want to sort this vector in ascending order. I don't know how to go about it. Your help will be welcome. Thank you*

Comment: The short answer is: use a comparison-based sorting algorithm in which the sequence of comparisons is independent of their results. This is the case in particular for [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). You then just need an implementation of homomorphic pairwise comparison and swapping (which is easy if you have an implementation of RELU, that I think has been done for CKKS).